# How to remove the extra white space underneath an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
/* Typography */

.header {font-family: "futura-pt", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.0em; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 0.1em;}
p {font-family: "futura-pt", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 1.0em; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 0.1em;}
/* Sizes */

.large-5 {font-size: 5.0em;}
.large-4 {font-size: 4.0em;}
.large-3 {font-size: 3.0em;}
.large-25 {font-size: 2.5em;}
.large-2 {font-size: 1.5em;}
.large-15 {font-size: 1.3em;}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.large-5 {font-size: 5.0em;}
.large-4 {font-size: 4.0em;}
.large-3 {font-size: 3.0em;}
.large-25 {font-size: 2.5em;}
.large-2 {font-size: 2.0em;}
.large-15 {font-size: 1.5em;}
}

/* Colours */

.white {color: #fff;}
.black {color: #000;}

/* Spacing */

.padding-top {padding-top: 2em;}
.padding-top-double {padding-top: 2em;}
.padding-top-triple {padding-top: 1em;}
.padding-bottom {padding-bottom: 1em;}

/* Links */

a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #fff; text-decoration: underline;}

/* General */

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

/* Structure */

.container {
    background-image: url("img/hd-sunset-river-HD-1200x1920.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #fff;

}


.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.content img {
    max-width: 100%;

}

my-email::after {
content: attr(data-domain);
}

my-email::before {
content: attr(data-user) "\0040";
}
```

This is my CSS code. I have tried to research the answer before asking the guys on Stack Overflow, I have tried `{display: block;}`and others but I've had no luck. I hope I have made an error with the code as this has caused some headache as I'm still learning from CSS and HTML.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Coming Soon</title>
   <link href="css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>

<body>


   <div class="container">
        <img src="img/hd-sunset-river-HD-1200x1920.jpg" width="1900" height="900">
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
        <img src="img/line.png">
        <p class="header large-2 white padding-top-triple">Coming This Fall 2015</p>
        <p class="white padding-top"><span class="header">Email: </span><a href="mailto:Jethwa96@hotmail.co.uk"><my-email data-user="Jethwa" data-domain="jedesigns.uk"></my-email></a></p> 
    </section> 





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly create a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/), would be easy for users to help you.

Comment: Its not working, ive tried to add my html and css to that website but the pictures wont show.

Comment: To use a jsfiddle or codepen, you'll have to link to the images absolute, instead of relative, so `http://www.website.com/img/image.jpg` instead of `/img/image.jpg`

Comment: heres my website link so you can see the problem, jedesigns.uk

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're placing a background in a separate `div` as an image block and then trying to align `div` with `section`. That's a little backwards and inside-out.

I suggest setting the background for the `section` instead and then wrapping inner contents in a `div` that you can easily position within `section`

**Section with background, inner div wrapping content:**

```
<section class="content">

    <div style="width:500px;
                margin:0 auto;
                top:25%;
                position:relative">

       <img src="http://jedesigns.uk/img/logo.png">
       <img src="http://jedesigns.uk/img/line.png">
       <p class="header large-2 white padding-top-triple">Coming This Fall 2015</p>
       <p class="white padding-top"><span class="header">Email: </span><a href="mailto:Jethwa96@hotmail.co.uk"><my-email data-user="Jethwa" data-domain="jedesigns.uk"></my-email></a></p> 

     </div>

</section>
```

**Then for your `section.content` CSS, change to:**

```
.content{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:url(http://jedesigns.uk/img/hd-sunset-river-HD-1200x1920.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**Here's jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z22hrvk9/**

Comment: Thats only changed my padding, the problem is with the logo as when i change the pixel height in css it goes down.

Comment: Make a screenshot of what you're trying to do. I don't see any padding set for this image. If you want to remove whitespace underneath the image `display:block` is the way. Otherwise explain more.

Comment: i cant add a screenshot as it wont let me, basically i have the background image which covers the whole screen and i have my logo with the text underneath, i had to put the height for the logo and text to 1200px and if i put it lower the white screen below goes down but also the logo and text go down the page rather than being in the centre.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: That has removed the white space but now the background image is too large as i want it to fit the whole screen.

Comment: Well if you want it to fit the whole screen, it's supposed to be large.